# Omitting a specific part of a column - awk

Tags: awk

- Every line is separated into parts with a semicolon
- In every part, there are dates in different formats
- Lines can include digits, letters and spaces.

I am trying to change the format of the date in the 6th part. It is currently like this

```
12 Nov 1999
```

but I only need the year. So how can I omit the day and month in the 6th parts of the lines without touching the other parts

```
12/31/1921;12 nov 1998; 13 September 2019; 13 Sep 2018; 12 August 1998; 12 Nov 1999; 27 November 1999; 13 Dec 1999; 14 December 1999; 15 D 1999
```

would turn into this

```
12/31/1921;12 nov 1998; 13 September 2019; 13 Sep 2018; 12 August 1998;1999; 27 November 1999; 13 Dec 1999; 14 December 1999; 15 D 1999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F ';' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { sub(".* ", "", $6); print }' file
```

The above parses each line of `file` as a set of `;`-delimited fields.  It applies a substitution that modifies the 6th field of each line.  The modification involves removing everything up to the last space character in the field's data. After modifying the 6th field, the modified line is printed.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`'s **`substr`** function:

```
awk -F';' '{ $6 = substr($6, length($6)-3) }1' OFS=';' inputfile
```